# Arduino Serial Input to Stop and Start

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I am trying to wait for user input to start a program operation and then when the user sends a stop command, the loop stops running. I have been unable to get the Serial port to keep reading an input while the loop is running.

So I want the user to Press 1 and then it'll go into the loop and will display the data from the interrupt. But I want it to keep monitoring the Serial Input so when I type in 2, I will get out of the loop and stop printing to the Serial Port.

The serial port isn't registering my second input.

I left out some of the code, but the important stuff should be there.

```
int userStart = 0;   // Holder for user input to start program
int userStop = 0; // Holder for user input to stop program

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(motorEncoderA, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(motorEncoderA, HIGH); // Pull up resistor
  pinMode(motorEncoderB, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(motorEncoderB,HIGH); // Pull up resistor

  // Interrupt on change of Pin A
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), encoderFunc, CHANGE); 

  Serial.print("Press 1 to start the Process & 2 to Stop");
}

void loop() {
if (Serial.available() > 0) 
{
   userStart = Serial.read();
   if (userStart = 1) {
       Serial.print('\n');
       while(userStop != 2) {  

       unsigned long timee = millis(); 

       // Only update if the shaft has moved
       if (encoderPositionLast != rotationCounter) {
           Serial.print("Time: ");
           Serial.print(timee);
           Serial.print(" Count: "); 
           Serial.print (rotationCounter);
           Serial.print('\n');
           encoderPositionLast = rotationCounter;
           Serial.print(userStart);

     }
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    userStop = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(userStop);
 }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe Arduino beta is the better place to ask. http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think your problem is that `userStart` and `userStop` should not be `1` and `2`, but `'1'` and `'2'`.

That said, there are some things in your code I dislike.

First of all why is everybody using `int` as the base type for all numeric variables? If one single `byte` is enough, use it. On 32bit machines `int` and `byte` are almost the same, but on 8bit ones working with `int`s wastes space and time.

Secondly, I highly discourage you to block the loop function, otherwise you won-t be able to do anything else. Instead, use a variable to track wheter you are running or not, update it with the serial interface, and then execute the code if you are running.

This code should do it. And IMHO it is much better than blocking the loop:

```
bool running = false;

void setup()
{
    ...
    running = false;
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0) 
    {
        switch(Serial.read())
        {
        case '1':
            running = true;
            Serial.print('\n');
            break;
        case '2':
            running = false;
            Serial.print("stopped");
            break;
        }
    }

    if (running)
    {
        unsigned long timee = millis(); 

        // Only update if the shaft has moved
        if (encoderPositionLast != rotationCounter) {
            Serial.print("Time: ");
            Serial.print(timee);
            Serial.print(" Count: "); 
            Serial.print (rotationCounter);
            Serial.print('\n');
            encoderPositionLast = rotationCounter;
            Serial.print("running");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks! At first I just threw something together to get it working, I have refined since.